# Volume of interpolated function rotated about Y axis in python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, numerical-integration

I have an (x,y) dataset with x domain (0,10). The dataset represents the cross-section of an object whose volume I want to find. My idea is to:

- linearly interpolate the dataset and obtain an interpolated function f(x).
- find the inverse of f(x) -> g(y)
- Perform a rotation integral of the function g(y) about the y-axis using the equation $\pi\int_a^b g(y)^2dy $

Here is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.integrate import quad

#assume (x,y) dataset has been imported as xvals, yvals

f = interpolate.interp1d(xvals,yvals)
area=quad(f,0,xvals[-1],limit=200) #this finds the cross sectional area, I need a 3D volume
```

how do I find the inverse g(y)? Or more generally, what is the best process for finding the volume enclosed by the shape rotated about the y axis?

Comment: what is `xdata` in the question ?  did you mean `xdata = xvals` ?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I have edited the code, everything is called xvals now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your attempt was quite close.

The trick is to create disks using `f(x)` as the radius. so each disk will have area `pi * f(x)**2`...

I believe this will be sufficient.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    ''' some function (to be roatated around the x-axis)'''
    return x**2

# make some x and y values
x = np.linspace(0, 3)
y = f(x) 


def g(x):
    ''' volume of the curve by integrating the circle slices '''
    radius = f(x)
    return np.pi * radius**2

volume, error = integrate.quad(g, 0, 3)

print(volume)
```

the result in this (example) case is `152.68`...

note, to do the rotation around the `y-axis`, you would need to switch x & y.